# VBA: Select rows below cell with specific value

Tags: vba

I'm trying to select a set of rows below the cell with the text "City"  and copy and paste them in different columns. Once the word "City" is found then copy all the next rows until the word Bird_type is found, copy and paste the rows and repeat the steps for all the cities in column A, something like this

[image]

I tried to code it in VBA but I'm only getting the first found row:

```
Sub test()


Dim city_find As String
Dim result As Integer
result = 2


Dim i As Integer

a = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a


    If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = "city" Then
    
      Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 6)).Copy
      
      Range("E100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    
    
       result = result + 1
    

    End If


Next i

   
End Sub
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I will use VBA `.Find()`:

```
Sub Calc()
  Dim s As Range, e As Range, nS As String
  Set s = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("City")
  If Not s Is Nothing Then
    Set e = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("City",s)
    If Not e Is Nothing Then
      Range(s,e).EntireRow.Copy
    End If
  End If
  Range("E100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
End Sub
```